# tinyxml2: Difference between doc.Print() and doc.SaveFile()

Tags: tinyxml2

I just asked myself if there are any differences between saving a file via `doc.Print()` and `doc.SaveFile()` in tinyxml2.

Here is a quick example:
Let's say we have a filepointer and a XML document from where we get our data.

```
FILE filepointer("MyFile.xml", "rb") //empty file
XMLDocument doc;
doc.LoadFile("SourceFile.xml")       //file we extract data from
```

Now we have two options to save the file.

```
XMLPrinter printer(filepointer)
doc.Print(&printer)
```

vs

```
doc.SaveFile(filepointer)
```

Are there any differences in these approaches?

Comment: Maybe go look in the [documentation](http://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_document.html)?

Comment: @Carl the only thing that is stated is the use of the printer to save the data to the memory. But beside that there is not more information on that. I am asking for the specific case when you want to save a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveFile` just does a `Print` internally, see https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/c0ff869500f3d2b828eeefc725a5bc1ff9b844f0/tinyxml2.cpp#L2247